Building and installing a python package locally
There is a PyPi package i wanted to install to access some API's. After installing I noticed the following error:
conda 24.7.1 requires requests<3,>=2.28.0, but you have requests 2.27.1 which is incompatible. 
So i tried to update the requests to 2.28.0 but got the following error:
XXX requires requests==2.27.1, but you have requests 2.28.0 which is incompatible. 
So, basically the package (XXX) i want to use is incompatible with Conda, however as it's open source, i made an issue, then i went on and also fixed this issue and made a pull request, however, as the project seems dead for 2 years, i doubt it ever gonna end up in the repository and be published on PyPi.
Can i build this package locally and install it for myself and use it? im new to python but i do have experience in other languages.
I tried github actions, but it builds for PyPi for releasing, which I don't want to do, because this is someone else's work and I just made some slight changes to fix a certain bug.

If the build steps are visible in the source code of the repository, you could simply run then manually on your local machine. After the build is done you can install the package locally using pip and the file you just built.
The exact steps to do the installation depend on the project.

Edit based on the comments provided:
You can probably get it working by doing pip install websocket-client==1.3.3 and copying this folder locally https://github.com/Tabdeal-Exchange/tabdeal-python/tree/master/tabdeal
Then you can just >>> import tabdeal if you are in the folder that contains the tabdeal folder you just downloaded.
If this approach works, you can set up your own build and packaging process around it. The easiest way would be to copy it from somewhere https://github.com/hirsimaki-markus/importmonkey would probably be suitable for copying minimal build steps from. Essentially it boils down to python -m build --wheel when you have the pyproject.toml and source code placed as shown in my example.

There is no build steps in the repository.

Can you share the repository? You could also create your own fork of the project.

I might try implementing each function in the package as a separate module in my project. I guess that's the only way I have.

This is the repository : https://github.com/Tabdeal-Exchange/tabdeal-python

i do have forked it, as i made a PR request in it for fixing the issue. i just don't know how to package it and install the modified files.

And this is the PyPi package: https://pypi.org/project/tabdeal-python/#history hasn't been updated in 2 years

You can probably get it working by doing pip install websocket-client==1.3.3 and copying this folder locally https://github.com/Tabdeal-Exchange/tabdeal-python/tree/master/tabdeal
Then you can just >>>import tabdeal if you are in the folder that contains the tabdeal folder.

as said, i first tried installing websocket, which was already installed, then i proceed with copying the data in tabdeal folder, however from my own modified repository at here: https://github.com/MohsenHNSJ/tabdeal-python-updated-dependencies/tree/forPackage/tabdeal which have the fix for dependency issue.
Then i tried import command, nothing was shown in terminal, so i proceeded. but other commands like python -m build --wheel does not work and always print out syntax error. i tired typing them myself, thought maybe copy and pasting was an issue, but still the same error happened.
